# Keep Controllers DRY : where to put shared methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry

My code is starting to have duplicates.... because I don't know where to put methods/functions that need to be accessed by (2) different controllers, and just to get it up quickly I just duplicated it.

So I have a users_controller, and a pages_controller and posts_controller.

On the users page, I have posts being displayed.

On the homepage, I also have posts being displayed.

Where should I put shared/common code so that the users_controller and pages_controller and posts_controller can all have access to ithese methods?

Right now, I have duplicated def methods in some controllers, and also some duplicate private methods in each controller.

---

On a related note, how can I access methods defined in one controller from another controller?

Comment: You can't access one controller's methods from another controller without hacking that yourself. The exception is the ApplicationController, from which all other controllers inherit by default, as explained below by Sydney.

Comment: Thanks MrYoshiji and Sydnet for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a module?

```
module ProductSharedMethods    
  def product_list
    Product.scoped
  end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include ProductSharedMethods

  def index
    @products = product_list
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have posts being displayed on two separate pages then use a partial. I don't know what version of rails you are using but newer versions have a views/application folder for shared partials.

If you have a method that is shared across more than one controller then put it in the application controller. Controllers are classes so follow all of the normal rules.

Hope that helps.

Comment: If the methods depend on each other or are closely related, a separate module might be a third choice, and also enables easier reusability. It would have to be included in the ApplicationController or the {Users,Pages,Posts}Controller however.